# Matching between Java Thread and native Linux thread

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, matching

I've got a tiny question on treads matching between **Java threads** created by **new Thread()** and gotten by `Thread.currentThread()` and **native Linux** thread could being created ty `pthread_create()` function call.

The question is: consider I would like to call some native Linux function with `pthread_t` parameter in order to get some operation on that thread, then is it possible to create thread in Java ( just like an ordrinary Java Thread ) get its **id** (by calling `Thread.getId()`) and pass that **id** through JNA call to native function ? Is it reasonable to expect quite a right functions behaviour ?

Or there is some other ( right ) way ?

Thank you very much for you time and for your patiance !!!!

Comment: Thead.getId() is a unique incrementing number known only to Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank all of you very much!

It seems that one of the easiest way to get such a behavior is to pass *ZERO* as threadId and expect thread with such a call being affined to a core you wish.

Of course there is another way to affine a thread to a core ( from Java PL ) but you have to decide upon cpu_set_t type substitution as well as its size.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a JNA call to a native function you write and that then queries the current thread. (`pthread_self` for example).

I don't know if the other way will work or is possible, a quick google didn't show anything but I'm not a JNA expert.

If you need a specific thread you could always write a JNA function that returns the linux thread handle. When your thread is started call that function and record the result for future use. I don't know if there are any guarantees made about a Java thread always corresponding to a given System thread though.

Comment: +1 I believe if you use thread id `0` it applies to the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using JNA, call `pthread_self()` (from the target thread) to get your `pthread_t` structure back (it is  opaque), then pass that to your function that accepts a `pthread_t`.  You may have to dig around in the *.h include files to figure out how to receive the `pthread_t` structure back into JNA.

UPDATE: this [mapping](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jna.user/594) might help.  Sounds like you just need the opaque `pthread_t` structure, you don't need to dig around inside the structure like that guys is trying to do.  But you can use his code as an example of the JNA mapping.

Comment: Thanks! I still didn't have a chance to check whether it is true or not, but I made some inquiries and found that Java operates native threads since 1.3. I gonna test this out and then post my experience.